# docker-machine connect to existing machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-machine

I have a docker swarm all hosted on AWS, created basically along the lines of [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/aws/).

To deploy our code, I need to be able to access this swarm separate of the computer where I created these instances. I don't see anywhere in the docs for the `docker-machine` `amazonec2` driver where I can use my AWS credentials to connect to these existing instances.

Some tutorials I came across use a `--url` argument to specify via the `docker-machine` url to connect to an existing instance, but I don't see that argument in my most recent docker-machine version.

Other tutorials mention TLS configuration and using that in conjunction with `docker-machine` to connect to existing instances, but given unique/secret AWS credentials, this seems redundant and adds a layer of complexity I hope I can avoid.

What is the recommended approach to this?

Unable to connect:

puttygen my-key.pem -L > id_rsa

docker-machine create --driver generic --generic-ip-address=ec2-....compute.amazonaws.com --generic-ssh-key id_rsa Swarm-Dev01

Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(Swarm-Dev01) Importing SSH key...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...

Comment: Maybe you are referencing to a [docker machine generic driver](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/) With generic driver you are able to provision existing remote docker installation and setup it with TLS.

Comment: @kand did you end up figuring this out? I've been trying myself and I cannot yet determine the correct SSH settings

Comment: I gave up on this and haven't worked on it since :/

Answer (score 10):

To get access to an existing instance, you can use the `docker-machine create --driver generic` command. The command will ssh onto the machine, make sure docker is installed, and then download certificates that it stores for future access e.g. using docker-compose.

Command:

```
docker-machine create \
    --driver generic \
    --generic-ip-address=<your_ip> \
    --generic-ssh-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
    vm
```

Documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/

Comment: Keep in mind that when you use this command:
"The docker daemon will be restarted, thus all running containers will be stopped."

Comment: Unable to connect with amazon key (pem)

Comment: You also need to make sure your SSH key is not password protected and you need to provide --generic-ssh-user yourusername unless you are able to SSH as root

Comment: --generic-ssh-user ubuntu